# Sniffing USB traffic between an Android app and a connected device

Tags: applications, usb

Is there any way to sniff USB traffic between an Android app and a connected device, like a drone controller?

Answer (score 1):

On a regular non-rooted device this is impossible.

On a rooted device it might be possible (but I would not know how). The common Linux solutions for capturing USB traffic require a special kernel module. If your kernel has no module support this would require to build a custom kernel with the USB sniffing kernel module included).

In both cases you still have the possibility to perform a man-in-the-middle (MitM) attack on the USB connection, e.g. by placing a special device in between that allows you to access the USB traffic on "cable level":

- https://www.csoonline.com/article/3087484/say-hello-to-badusb-20-usb-man-in-the-middle-attack-proof-of-concept.html
- Or You could use a ["Facedancer" board + software](https://github.com/usb-tools/Facedancer)